Adding a custom serialize method to cache-manager in NestJS
I am migrating a NodeJS project to NestJS and so switched from using the redis library directly to use the cache-manager with redistore.
However, it seems that the cache manager uses JSON.stringify/JSON.parse as serializer logic. That is, anything that is stored in the cache is serialized with JSON.stringify and anything that is read from the cache is de-serialized with JSON.parse.
This causes all values that are stored in redis to have escaped quotes.
For example:
GET "test-key"
Now returns "\"test-value\"" instead of simply "test-value".
This would not be an issue if not that my cache is currently shared with other services and the format has to remain the same.
Is there any way to customise the serialization logic of the cache-manager in NestJS? If not, any suggestion on how to solve this?
